# How to animate scaling a view to fit the screen size?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to animate scaling a view to fit the screen. On the click of an icon, a view should expand and fit the screen and on clicking back, it should return back to it's normal size. We have *ScaleTo* property for animation. But the aspect ratio of a view is maintained if we give scaling factor. Here's a part of the code.

```
    chartFrame.AnchorX = 0;
    chartFrame.AnchorY = 1;
    chartFrame.ScaleTo(chartFrame.Scale * 1.75, 500, Easing.SpringIn);
```

I also find that there are *ScaleX* and *ScaleY* property available but it's not possible to animate. I would like to know how can we animate the scaling to fit the screen. Thank you!
[image: Expand a View]

Comment: Do you mean to scale the Width and Height with separate factors?

Comment: Yes. And also animate it while doing so.

Comment: I have added an answer please do check if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can animate properties by writing Custom animation using Animation class.

[MSDocs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom)

Simply animate ScaleX and ScaleY separately.

Xaml code:

```
  <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Button
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,0.2"
            Text="Animate scaling"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <BoxView
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="LightCoral"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,0.3,0.3"
            x:Name="scalingBox">
        </BoxView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Button click in CS code:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Animation XShrinkAnimation = new Animation(
            f => this.scalingBox.ScaleX = f,
            2,
            1);
        Animation YShrinkAnimation = new Animation(
            f => this.scalingBox.ScaleY = f,
            3,
            1);
        Animation XGrowAnimation = new Animation(
            f => this.scalingBox.ScaleX = f,
            1,
            2);
        Animation YGrowAnimation = new Animation(
            f => this.scalingBox.ScaleY = f,
            1,
            3);


        XGrowAnimation.Commit(this.scalingBox, "XGrowAnimation", 500);
        YGrowAnimation.Commit(this.scalingBox, "YGrowAnimation", 500);

        await Task.Delay(500);

        YShrinkAnimation.Commit(this.scalingBox, "XShrinkAnimation", 250);
        XShrinkAnimation.Commit(this.scalingBox, "YShrinkAnimation", 250);
    }
```

UI result

[image: Result UI]

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out as well!

Comment: This woks well!

Answer (score 2):

You should change Event Handler as **async**

For example I invoke it when click the button

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >

    <Label x:Name="label" BackgroundColor="Red" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,0.25,0.25" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>

    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="click" WidthRequest="100" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   label.AnchorX = 0;
   label.AnchorY = 1;

   await label.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(label.Bounds.X,label.Bounds.Y,label.Bounds.Width*2.0, label.Bounds.Width * 0.5), 500, Easing.SpringIn);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not for invoking. If we set the scaling factor (eg., label.Scale * 1.75), it scales the view evenly without changing the aspect ratio. But I need to scale it to a different aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you. The width seems to fit the screen. But the height remains the same. What attribute should I change?

Comment: I set the size just for demo , you should set it as you need .

Comment: And you can try ikhil's answer as well , it use custom animation :)